# Subnetting Access Problem

Tags: ip, ipv4, subnet, ip-address, packet-tracer

I am learning subnetting, and I am using Packet Tracer to design a network for a building with five storeys. I have used subnetting, with each floor having its own subnet. As a result, it is not possible for PCs on other floors to access the email and storage servers which are located in the IT-services department.
[image]

I want all computers to be able to access the email and storage servers, even if they are on a different floor. Would this negatively impact access?

What possible modifications to the network would be needed to achieve this access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have different networks, but no router. Routers route packets between networks, so different networks require a router to communicate. If your Switch 5 is a layer-3 switch, you could enable routing on it, or you need to replace it with a stand-alone router.